# Are all Hadamard matrices equivalent to their transposes?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, hadamard-matrices

Hadamard matrices are matrices such
$H * H^T = nE$, and all columns are pairwise orthogonal(and all raws are pairwise orthogonal)

The Hadamard matrices are equivalent(~) if it is possible to obtain one from the other by pairwise swapping rows (columns) or multiplying a row (column) by -1.

And the question : is this statement always true $H \sim H^T$?

I have been trying to obtain something good for quite a while.
Assuming that $H \sim H^T$, quite a few good properties arise, but I cannot find anything substantial.

For example, if $H \sim H^T$, then $H = Q*H^T*M$, where $Q$ and M are matrix products that interchange two columns (rows) and multiply a column (row) by -1. From this, it follows that $Q^-1 = Q^T$, and similarly for $M$.

Comment: Not sure why you are deleting and repost the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663671/is-every-hadamard-matrix-equivalent-to-its-transpose). Seems like there are some helpful comments in the old post.

Comment: @ArcticChar First edit of that post was wrong, So comments are irrelevant to the question stated there

Comment: As @ArcticChar, it is not appropriate to delete a question and then reask it.  In the future, please use the [edit] button to make clarifications.